# C - Sort float array while keeping track of indices

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have an array of 3 floating point values:

```
float norms[3];

norms[0] = 0.4;
norms[1] = 3.2;
norms[2] = 1.7;
```

I want to sort this array in descending order *while keeping track of the original indexes of the values in the array*.

In other words, given the array `norms[] = {0.4, 3.2, 1.7}` with corresponding indices `{0, 1, 2}`, I basically want to obtain an array of corresponding `ints` that reflects the original positions of the `float` values in `norms[]` following a descending sort. In this case it would be `{1, 2, 0}`.

What is the best/cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: Create an array of type int with the same size containing the indices. When sorting the float array simply mirror any swap operation on your int array.

Comment: Use a struct with an index field, write the index of each element before sorting, and that will retain the original position in the array.

Comment: @Lundin that would not achieve what the question is asking

Comment: @Lundin And exactly what will that achieve? Where does your "solution" create the indexing that the original poster wants? You end up with a sorted and an unsorted array, but you don't have the indexing between the two and there is no way of getting it without "muddy-thinking, pre-mature optimization algorithms".

Comment: @DimitarSlavchev I'll let the moderator who deleted whatever 4 year old comment you are referring to answer that question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a structure to store the value as well as index and then sort according to value.

```
struct str
{
    float value;
    int index;
};

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    struct str *a1 = (struct str *)a;
    struct str *a2 = (struct str *)b;
    if ((*a1).value > (*a2).value)
        return -1;
    else if ((*a1).value < (*a2).value)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    float arr[3] = {0.4, 3.12, 1.7};
    struct str objects[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        objects[i].value = arr[i];
        objects[i].index = i;
    }
    //sort objects array according to value maybe using qsort
    qsort(objects, 3, sizeof(objects[0]), cmp);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%d ", objects[i].index); //will give 1 2 0
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use any sorting algorithm 'aliasing' the original array access. Example with bubblesort

```
int len = 3;
bool switched = false;

float myFloatArr[3];
int myFloatIndex[3] = {0, 1, 2};

do
{
    switched = false;
    for(i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(myFloatArr[myFloatIndex[i - 1]] < myFloatArr[myFloatIndex[i]])
        {
            int temp = myFloatIndex[i];
            myFloatIndex[i] = myFloatIndex[i - 1];
            myFloatIndex[i - 1] = temp;
            switched = true;
        }
    }
}
while(switched);
```

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest way i can think of is to create a structure which contains both float and index.

```
typedef struct str {
float val;
int index;
} str;
```

then create an array of this structure and sort it according to `val`.

Comment: How can we do this ? Please include a fuller example.